# How to iterate over points in VTK while finding the Nearest Neighbors of each point?

Tags: for-loop, iterator, vtk

I am using VTK for a project an just can not seem to figure out a section of it. I am trying to iterate through several thousand points and find the 5 closest points every point. Seems like a simple for loop operation but my problem is that for some reason, I am being told that the same 5 points are the closest point for every point in my data...which I know is not true. I will attach the bit of code I am describing Below:

```
  //test
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource> pointSource =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPointSource>::New();
   pointSource->SetNumberOfPoints( Output->GetNumberOfPoints() );
   pointSource->Update();

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkKdTreePointLocator> Tree =
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkKdTreePointLocator>::New();
   Tree->SetDataSet( pointSource->GetOutput() );
   Tree->BuildLocator();

   unsigned int k = 5;
   double testpoint[3];

   vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> result = 
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();

   for(vtkIdType n = 0; n < Output->GetNumberOfPoints(); n++)
     {

     result->Reset();
     Output->GetPoint( n,testpoint );
     Tree->Update();
     std::cout << "Point: " << testpoint[0] << ", " << testpoint[1] << ", " << testpoint[2] << ": " << endl;

     Tree->FindClosestNPoints(k, testpoint, result);

     for(vtkIdType i = 0; i < k; i++)
       {
       vtkIdType point_ind = result->GetId(i);
       double p[3];
       pointSource->GetOutput()->GetPoint(point_ind, p);
       std::cout << "Closest point " << i+1 << ": Point "
       << point_ind << ": (" << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ", " << p[2] << ")" << std::endl;
       }

     }
     //end test
```

This is doing what I am trying to do...It is printing out the 5 closest points to the a point of interested, but despite the point of interest changing, the 5 closest points are remaining the same. I am assuming I am just passing over a small detail in my code but I could be wrong. If you need anymore information to help, just ask away.

Thank you for your time and help,
Luke H

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem...I was using /vtkPointSource which generates random points and I was feeding in my points into that function. I am not sure why, but that made getting results out very difficult but once I passed in the correct information and placed a Reset() on the point Id array and the result Id array, it works like a champ. Hopefully this will same others some trouble because I spent some hrs working on this.

Luke H

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkKdTreePointLocator> Tree =
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkKdTreePointLocator>::New();
 Tree->SetDataSet( Output );
 Tree->BuildLocator();

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> result = 
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();

 vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList> point_ind =
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkIdList>::New();

 unsigned int k = 5;

 double testpoint[3];

 for( vtkIdType n = 0; n < Output->GetNumberOfPoints(); n++ )
   {

   Output->GetPoint( n,testpoint );
   std::cout << "Point: " << testpoint[0] << ", " << testpoint[1] 
     << ", " << testpoint[2] << ": " << endl;

   Tree->FindClosestNPoints( k, testpoint, result );

   for(vtkIdType i = 0; i < k; i++)
     {

 vtkIdType point_ind = result->GetId( i );

     double p[3];

     Output->GetPoint( point_ind, p );
 std::cout << "Closest point " << i+1 << ": Point "
   << point_ind << ": (" << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << ", " 
       << p[2] << ")" << std::endl;

    }

    result->Reset();
point_ind->Reset();

  }
```